# Using Scrapy and the HTML file returned is blacked out in the directory and opens to a 404 error. Any idea why?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The code I'm using is pretty much cut and paste from the tutorial on their site.

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://overwatchleague.com/en-us/players'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

The code runs ok but the HTML file it saves has a blacked out icon, and opens to a 404 page.

EDIT: Looking into it more, it seems that this is due to some anti-scraping procedures. Is getting around this feasible/possible?

Comment: That website uses Javascript to load the information. You need to use [Scrapy Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/) to render the Javascript. Alternatively, can't you just use their [official API](https://develop.battle.net/)?

Comment: Thanks I'll look into splash! I know I can use the API, but part of this project is learning web scraping for me haha.